# Cloud based solution - Data Migration Challenges?

Tags: cloud-hosting, amazon-cloudfront

I have a question on cloud based systems. The fundamental guiding principle is 'Pay per use', 'Software as Service' or 'Infrastructure as Service'. These are multiple offerings by service providers.

Assume I have a Microsoft Cloud based system with SQL Azure as its Database. Tomorrow I would like to port it to another cloud provider ex-Amazon.

Are we in a state where we have a seamless migration approach for moving the application data from one cloud based service provider to another.

My Question was more focussed on in long term basis how application can be managed in cloud.

Answer (score 0):

Found an article which answers my question

5 costly cloud migration mistakes - http://www.privatecloud.com/blog/?fbid=xEEiydK0SQY

Answer (score 0):

I read your question as **portability of solutions** built upon data hosted in cloud. This is a challenging problem as on date. There are no standards which direct the portability requirements but sure there are tools / services which help you in overcoming the absence of standards of portability.

Few points (challenges to watch out for) which I had considered in such migrations are -

1. **Service offering impedance** - Service offering between cloud providers are driven by competition and directed by standards. e.g. AWS IAM does not have direct mapping to Azure Active Directory. Though you could federate them using SAML standard. If you are working for customer who want to migrate from AWS to Azure (just for conversation sake) there is no Out of Box solution, you would need to build a tailored tool for this. Whereas the reverse (Azure AD -> AWS) would be possible if not as PaaS at least as IaaS. Granularity of securable (Object could be protected in AWS using policies, Azure has SAS and would require custom built SAS provider to  offer you similar functionality) between cloud service providers offer the greatest security challenge. Service impedance could also manifest in the form of say in Azure you could have Blob which are of different types - Page, Append, Block. However, in AWS there are no such categories for the S3 bucket object. Now, if you have built your application logic around the idea of assuming an Append blob in Azure and now you are migrating the application to AWS you would need to write the logic to download the object, add the data you want and then upload the new object along with deleting the existing object. Such, changes might sometimes might bear consequences of architectural changes.
2. **SLA impedance** - Services are metered on certain basic units which are common across cloud service providers. However, there are subtle differences in the measurement units and parameters used to bill you. e.g. AWS would charge unstructured storage based on - Region, Size, Volume of requests, Volume of data transfer out (egress) of AWS infrastructure in units of GB. Whereas, Azure would charge for same unstructured storage based on - Region, Size, Volume of requests, Volume of data egress from Azure infra, and Data redundancy option you would select. Thus, while you migrate you would need to measure such SLA differences and select the right service plan in target platform. If you are migrating from Azure to AWS and had redundancy based SLA now you might have to pay more or bring other service in AWS to have continuity in your service offerings.
3. **Tooling & API impedance** - Cloud service provider have very diverse support for programmable interfaces. But they need not be similar between two of them. REST communication protocol, JSON / XML standards could rescue us. It is very likely for those who have been in cloud for some time would have established tools that help administer lifecycle of services in cloud. Migrating such customer with their toolset would need consideration of the effort you would need to replace the service provider offered tools and the effort to change any proprietary tool that would have been built using the API's of service provider.

In the migration assignments I use the Operating System analogy to explain (myself and customer) the challenges. i.e. in the beginning there OS where each had special capabilities but all of them lacked to be compatible with each other and communicate and exchange data with each other. This impacted business which started realizing this challenge. Slowly standards evolved and now we could exchange data and make the OS talk to each other (Virtualization). Consider Cloud platform as OS and then give it some time (dont know how much) for it to overcome such impedance. Till then we would face challenges (which certainly could be overcome to good extent) in moving from one service provider to another using tools like the one you had listed and few more and services of consultants to address very specific migration challenge in a business context.

Answer (score 0):

All of the following are to be solved with a proper vendor.
First of all, main risk in cloud migration is data corruption - anomalies or redundant or duplicated data, or absence of previously existing data -  happens because of a possible lack of maximum synchronization between source & target cloud.
Second, there is a semantic risk - no data loss or corruption is done, migration's considered to be successful, but sometimes meaning of legacy column and target column hold same meaning but their measurement is different and the meaning of data is completely different.
to me, those are the 2 major problems, as i've experienced them in the past with an unsuccessful vendor. cloud migration proper service is not cheap, therefore i strongly recommend to go for the right choice for you. i've changed to cloudendure and i am satisfied with them as a cloud vendor. once again, not a cheap service - but i believe that if you put money in it, you deserve to get the best.

Answer (score 0):

TL;DR: Build for the lowest common denominator across IaaS providers.

---

The simple answer to doing this is to use the IaaS provider strictly only for their infrastructure and not for their 'services'.

A good way to do this could be to only do things in your cloud application that terraform allows you to do. Interestingly, tools like Docker, Kubernetes make infrastructure agnostic applications vastly easier and there is a phenomenal rise in the number of solutions that help you do this. Applications built on [Openshift](https://www.openshift.com), [cloudfoundry](https://www.cloudfoundry.org) etc. help you normalise across cloud vendors. There are smaller more developer friendly tools emerging too, that use k8s/docker to build vendor agnostic applications: [deis](http://deis.io/), [dokku](https://github.com/dokku/dokku), [hasura](https://hasura.io). Disclaimer: I work at Hasura.

---

To answer your questions specifically:

> Assume I have a Microsoft Cloud based system with SQL Azure as its
>   Database. Tomorrow I would like to port it to another cloud provider
>   ex-Amazon.

No, if you do this, you can't be "multi cloud".

> Are we in a state where we have a seamless migration approach for
>   moving the application data from one cloud based service provider to
>   another.

We're not there completely yet. But we're definitely moving towards that. Refer details I shared above.